# am having data as ["1","2","3"] in one column of table and another table with id 1 and tip dont rub, how to fetch the data

Tags: php, sql, jquery-mobile

tips as ["45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56"] and in another table am having the tips as id 45 tip wash your eyes, id 46 tip dont rub your eyes how to split the array and according to that i have to get particular tip and to be printed any suggestions please. how to search and combine and get the data and the data has to be placed in listview in jquery mobile any suggestions are accepted thanks

at present am able to get as

```
 <?php
include('libraries/config.php');
$getID = $_GET['id'];
//echo $getID;
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category where categoryID = ?");
 if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']))) {
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
   // print_r($row);
  // echo $row['tips'];
  }

}
 ?>
```

here the output is ["1","2","3"] this one i have to use split it as 1 2 and 3 and in query i have to pass it and from second table by passing this id i have to get the tip column data.

Comment: sounds like you need to normalise your db first

Comment: sorry i didn't get you? can you explain please

Comment: you should never have  [“1”,“2”,“3”] in one column

Comment: the client given the database as the column with form as above. and in another table am having values as 1 dont rub   2 clean i have to get those by passing this value one by one. how to do this please

Comment: can't we split in and store in array as [1,2,3]   please help me dagon